# Network timeouts with CentOS 7 server running in the same network (Syn-Flooding)

Tags: centos7, timeout, denial-of-service, flooding, port-scanning

As described above, I'm having problems with my network during my CentOS 7 running.

When I first encountered problems with my network I tried to permanently run ping on the main router in the same network. The ping request produced Request timeout errors every time in a while. I switched off range off network devices to find the one eventually responsible for those timeouts. Timeouts are disappearing as soon as I turn off the network service on CentOS. I tried turning off the firewalld service but it didn't helped.

My router is Fritz Box 7360 if it's going to be helpfull.

All services I have installed are samba, httpd, MariaDB and SSH.

Does someone already encountered similar problem?

Thank you in advance
PatVax

Edit 1: In /var/log/messages I'm getting `nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet` error in the same time those timeouts occur. What could be causing this problem?

Edit 2: I made some research on nf_conntrack and I eventually found out that at the time of timeouts nf_conntrack tracked connections count drastically rises (over 200 000 connections tracked). I checked out what does conntections actually are and it turned out all those connections come from two diffrent IPs (119.29.186.43 and 119.29.233.123) and two diffrent ports (16925 and 12725). For the IP address of my machine there are port numbers in full 0 - 65535 range which seems like open ports scanns. The odd thing is, no ports are forwarded on my router to the Internet so how can those connections even reach my machine?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your IP address scheme set up, is there the possibility of an IP conflict?

Comment: I assigned separate Adresses for all static devices like Clients or Servers and DHCP works in range where no static device is configured, so I would say there's no conflict. When the server is down the ip seems free to use.

Comment: May be you use server's Ethernet port which is used for system and management at one time. Check in BIOS that the same static IP address isn't used on management interface.

Comment: In BIOS I didn't found any of such entries so it's probably not the case.

Comment: I editted my post.